# Click and Touch events on <a> tags in Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, ios

In Lightning, we should always be using `e.force:navigateToSObject` or `e.force:navigateToURL` instead of links like `<a href="whatever>`. So, I made a custom Link component to avoid having to have Javascript controllers all over the place just to handle links:

Component:

```
<aura:component access="global">

    <aura:attribute name="type" type="String" default="a" />
    <aura:attribute name="class" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="relativeUrl" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="id" type="String" />

    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.type == 'button'}">
        <button id="{!v.id}" class="{!v.class}" onclick="{!c.onClick}">
            {!v.body}
        </button>
        <aura:set attribute="else">
            <a id="{!v.id}" class="{!v.class}" onclick="{!c.onClick}">
                {!v.body}
            </a>
        </aura:set>
    </aura:if>

</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
({
    onClick : function(component, event, helper) {
        var recordId = component.get('v.recordId');
        var navEvt;
        if(recordId) {
            navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
            navEvt.setParam("recordId", recordId);
        } else {
            navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
            navEvt.setParam("url", component.get('v.relativeUrl'));
        }
        navEvt.fire();
    }
})
```

This is all great on Desktop, but the links don't work on Safari/iOS. The button version does, but not the `<a>` version.

Now, the Lightning docs say that the framework handles turning an onclick into a touch event:

> Don’t Use onclick and ontouchend Events
>
> You can’t use different actions for onclick and ontouchend events in a
>   component. The framework translates touch-tap events into clicks and
>   activates any onclick handlers that are present.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_anti_patterns.htm

So, this implies that I shouldn't need to add a ontouchend event to my `<a>` tag, but doing so does make my links work on iPad. Is this a bug in the framework? Am I being stupid about how to use `<a>` tags in Lightning? Unfortunately, googling about anything related to `<a>` is never very helpful.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this? Trying to resolve the same issue.

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember what we did to solve this in the end. I couldn't use the suggested answer below of using a styled span because I was working with some design constraints.

Answer (score 0):

I've found `a` tags with an onclick event to be problematic too.

So, this is just a suggestion, but try a different approach.  Create a `span` with an onclick event and style it like an `a` element.  This has been successful for myself in lightning communities.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a id="{!v.id}" class="{!v.class}" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="{!c.onClick}">
{!v.body}    </a>
```

> Please use href="javascript:void(0)" in anchor tag of your code.

Comment: Please do not ask for upvotes.  I have edited your post to remove that.